# Image available on server but failed to load the given URL

Tags: apache, https

I have a scenario that the image is available on the server on the said path
the whole system is running on apache with https (ssl installed and configured properly)
In my application when i generate the path and assign the same to the output (Html) it dose not show the image. Infact it says like the resource could not be loaded. But the same code works on local and many other server but on this 1 server.
Secondly if i do a view source on the same, copy the url and open the same url in browser - it opens up properly - without any issue / trouble but cannot find the same into the out generated by the app..

Any clue as why such thing should be happening??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake - i realized those were tagged under folder ads and were blocked by ad block plus. Got the resolution :)